# Passing an array between forms C++ CLR

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'd like to pass a generated array (arNum[20]) from Form number 1(MyForm.h) to Form number 2(MyForm1.h) in the following function

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    int x;
    int arNum[20];
    if (!int::TryParse(txtNodes->Text, x)) 
        MessageBox::Show("First box wasn't an integer");

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < txtNumbers->Text->Length; i+=2)
        {
            if (!(int)txtNumbers->Text[i])
            {
                MessageBox::Show("Invalid Input!");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                arNum[i] = (int)txtNumbers->Text[i];
            }
        }
        MessageBox::Show("Data submitted correctly.");
        MyForm1 ^form = gcnew MyForm1();
        form->
    }


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what's your specific problem? You didn't even ask a question.

Comment: How to implement code to pass an array from this current above code to another form(MyForm2.h)

Comment: _@Youssef_ Well, provide some appropriate function in `MyForm2` to do so?

Comment: MyForm2.h is an empty basic form, I just want a way to pass it from one to another.

Comment: @Ðаn It's required for a class project to use this type of GUI

Comment: You will have to add a public function to the MyForm1 class.  Or add another constructor to MyForm1.  Since you are trying to pass an unmanaged array, it needs two arguments, int array[] and size_t length.  Some odds that you meant to use `array<int>^`, the managed flavor, but that's hard to guess from the question.  Odd to get stuck on this btw, you'll get bogged down a lot more if this is a hangup.  Maybe there is more to it, but I can't see it.